# I want to install skype but i have to authenticate first, the problem is that i do not know the password. Where can i find the required password?

Tags: administrator

I've just bought a new laptop (dell) and i have Ubuntu. I am trying to install some programs but if i want to install them i need authenticate and to write a "password for dell" but i don't know it. Also when i turn on my laptop I'm signed in as a "Dell" user and it also has the password that I don't know. I've checked in instructions if there's anything about this but there is not. When I turned the laptop for the first time it didn't ask me to log in, but it automatically logged me in with that "Dell" user. Where can I find that password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

[This is how to reset password](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/167850).

I suggest also creating a new user with administrative rights and remove that "Dell" user.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there some easier way to do this? I'm not really good with this stuff